# How to get data from post request in back-end / nodeJS / React

Tags: node.js, reactjs

In my React app i have a button which try to access my back end with a post request with axios :

```
const sendComment = () => {
    console.log(message)
    axios.post('http://localhost:3002/api/comments/add', message)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
    })
  }
```

my back-end has this route built in :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3002;
const connection = require('./conf');
const cors = require('cors');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))


app.get('/api/comments', (req, res) => {

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM comments', (err, results) => {

      if (err) {

        res.status(500).send('Erreur lors de la récupération des données');
      } else {
        res.json(results);
      }
    });
  });

app.post('/api/comments/add', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body, res)
}) ;

app.listen(port, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    throw new Error('Something bad happened...');
  }

  console.log(`Server is listening on ${port}`);
});
```

When i try the route with postman, it log me the data from body, but when i do it via my front end, i only get back an empty object.

I've read tons of documentation & tutorials, still can't find what is the correct approch to get the data in my back end, and then stock it in my database.

Comment: Are you submitting from a form or through a fetch body?
If by a fetch use:
`app.use(express.json())` to properly parse the incoming request.

Comment: the button which hold the sendComment onClick is not inside a form. It just take a state (comment) and try to access my backend

Comment: try adding this middleware `app.use(bodyParser.json())` after `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

install qs parser with `npm i qs` and then:

```
import * as qs from qs

const sendComment = () => {
    console.log(message)
    axios.post('http://localhost:3002/api/comments/add', qs.stringify(message))
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
    })
  }
```

and if this dont work try console.log() the body in the backend to check if the data is passed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

**Check out the below: (It may help)**

When you use the axios for handle the api requests, check the **headers** like(Accept, Authorization and ...) and data that you pass correctly:

**Example: (try this)**

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class CommentsForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      message: ''
    };

    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const {name, message} = this.state;

    axios.post('http://localhost:3002/api/comments/add', {
      name, // same syntax name: name
      message // same syntax message: message
    },{
      headers:{
        Accept: 'application/json',
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token // if you use token
     }
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });

    this.setState({
      name: '',
      message: ''
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            name="name"
            type="text"
            checked={this.state.name}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
        <br />
          <textarea
            name="message"
            type="text"
            value={this.state.message}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default CommentsForm;
```

If you have any questions, leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think your back end needs `app.post()` handler needs a bit fixing. Since the `app.post()` handler doesn't use `res` to send a response to the client, you're getting an empty object. Try adding a response to the `app.post()` handler.

**EDIT**

After I *actually* read the question right, I saw that my answer was completely off. So, here's a new one.

A few checks:

1. Make sure you *are* passing in the data (you probably are),
2. Make sure you are specifying Content-type and receiving it correctly in the server,

Otherwise, try this:

```js
app.post((req, res) => {
   let reqData = null;
   req.on("data", chunk => {
      //saving the data to a variable
      reqData = chunk;
      if(reqData.length > 1e7) {
         //what to do if data is too long
      }
   });
   req.on("end", () => {
      //do whatever is needed with the data, i.e:
      console.log(reqData);
   });
});
```